# Why would my archive build just fine but my debug would fail on the device?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm putting this here in hopes of helping someone else down the road:

Scenario:
React-native ios project
Things are working great and then they don't.  Can run in the simulator, but when you try to run on the device you get codesign error saying the package is not valid: /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
Archive works too.

What is destroying productivity?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot and wasted hours on this.

I had deleted the test project out of my react-native setup and had not removed the target from the project browser.  Once I removed the test target things started working again.

Happy programming.